# ViewModels + Hilt : cannot inline bytecode built with JVM target 1.8 into bytecode that is being built with JVM target 1.6

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle, android-viewmodel, dagger-hilt

I am using view models and Hilt in my android app (Kotlin). But I have a issue when initializing my
View model :

`private val myViewModel: MyViewModel by viewModels()`

The app compile fine and I can run it, but Android Studio indicates an error, and when I move my cursor above it I have the following message :

*Cannot inline bytecode built with JVM target 1.8 into bytecode that is being built with JVM target 1.6. Please specify proper '-jvm-target'*

In my build gradle I have specified Java 1.8 for Compile option (even for Kotlin).

```
compileOptions {
   sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
   targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
kotlinOptions {
   jvmTarget = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
```

Here are the annotations for my viewmodel and my fragment

```
@HiltViewModel
class MyViewModel: ViewModel()
```

And

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class MyFragment: Fragment()
```

some of my dependencies :

```
'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.5.0'
'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.0'
'com.google.dagger:hilt-android:2.35'
'com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:2.35'
"androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.2.0"
```

Has anyone faced a similar issue ? Thank you for your help !

Comment: can you add your dependencies once too?

Comment: Have you annotated your viewModel and Fragment / Activity properly ?

Comment: Hi, I added missing elements to my question

Answer (score 7):

I have the same issue and nothing helped me except reducing Kotlin version. I have put 1.5.10 instead of 1.5.31 and error disappeared.
My corrections in build.gradle file as follow:

buildscript {
ext.kotlin_version = '1.5.10'

...

dependencies {
classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"

Seems here is something wrong with new Kotlin version.

Comment: Only thing that helped me. I hate Android development so much.

Answer (score 1):

```
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
kotlinOptions {
    jvmTarget = '1.8' // <---- 
}
```

include '1.8' rather than JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8, sometimes compiler have difficulty in detecting